# jquery bind button click event fails

Tags: jquery, events, bind

test.html:

```
 <html> 
     <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
        <input id="but2" type="button" value="2"/>
     </body>
 </html>
```

jquery-1.4.2.js is downloaded from http://jquery.com/

test.js:

```
var fn=function(){
  alert('success!');
};

$('#but2').click(fn);
```

When clicked the button, nothing happened. I debugged for very long time but didn't find the root cause. Please help.

Comment: It is because at the moment the event handler should be attached, jQuery cannot find the element with ID `but2` as the DOM is not loaded yet. Either move the script to the button of the page or, and this is the preferred solution, do as Patrick suggests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap it such that the code doesn't run until the document has loaded.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/ApDKU/

```
$(function() {
    var fn=function(){
      alert('success!');
    };

    $('#but2').click(fn);
});
```

Doing:

```
$(function() {...});
```

...is the same as

```
$(document).ready(function() {...});
```

...which cause the code inside to run only after the `<body>` tag has finished loading.

The way you had it, the code that attached the `click` handler to `#but2` was running *before* `#but2` had loaded onto the page.

Comment: "patrick dw"'s method works!! Thank you so much!!
By the way, there is a small problem with the code from http://jsfiddle.net/ApDKU/. If some one copy the js code directly from http://jsfiddle.net/ApDKU/, there are some invisible characters included and the code doesn't run.  I noticed it in firebug. I deleted the invisible characters and the code run like a charm.

Comment: @peter - Yeah, I don't know what those characters are. They're always there, and they really mess me up sometimes. Glad you got it working. :o)